# NSTableView Make Cell Editable Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

The requirement is something like this, 
-- Similar to pList , there would be an + button, when user select this, it should make the last row editable,

Any idea how its feasible, i am able to get which row is selected, but not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the row to be editable via the provided methods.

```
NSCell *lastCell; // Find last cell
[lastCell setEditable: YES];
```